# "Template to be deleted is in use" while upgrading

Tags: upgrade

I am upgrading my freshly installed Sitecore 8.1 instance to 9.1 and I am receiving an error and two warnings after analyzing the package showing that template to be deleted is in use.[image]

Comment: Seems like that template is in use... ;) Have you tried deleting the items that use that template?

Comment: Did you check where the template is used? You can do that in the content editor (the links button in the navigate bar).

Comment: yes i have manually deleted that template and also remove the links to that template but the gives 3 colisions and also some warnings .

Comment: Try rebuilding the Links database beforehand.

Comment: done rebuilding the databases , still it shows the same

Comment: Why are you upgrading from fresh Sitecore 8.1 to 9.1? You can just install fresh Sitecore 9.1 if you had fresh 8.1

Comment: @PeterProcházka I assume he is trying out a test upgrade :-)

Comment: correct peter . did it without deleting the tamplate . soled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would leave the template as it is and continue with the upgrade. Sitecore will do it by default since you can see "leave template" in the Action column.

Since these are system templates/items and since they are not been modified (i.e. you mentioned this is a fresh install) I would not be too much worries about that.

I can see "/sitecore/templates/System/Experience Explorer/Preset" exists both on 8.1 & 9.1 fresh installs. 
But "/sitecore/templates/System/Experience Explorer/Preset**s**" template only exists on 8.1 instance.

So, it seems that template has been removed in 9.1

After the upgrade please try to remove "/sitecore/templates/System/Experience Explorer/Preset**s**" template in 9.1